# Why are there 3 chrome.exe processes immediately upon launch?

Tags: process, google-chrome, threads

I am aware that chrome.exe uses a new process per browser tab, but why do I get 3 chrome.exe processes in the process list immediately upon launch?

Comment: We need more information.  Chrome has configuration tabs that can explain this behavior.   I suggest you use these reporting capabilities to determine the information you seek.

Comment: Chrome Menu > Tools > Task Manager. You will see the list of tasks that are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most extensions are starting an own process, too.

Chromes built-in task-manager should be revealing more exactly what is running.